flask session is expiring when i am redirection to a another server domain how to keep the session alive
def generate_url():
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            session.permanent = True
            review_payment.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=30)

i am generating an url in this function and redirecting to that url to perform some specific task when i am again coming back to my domain i am not able to access my session its empty i want to keep it alive
session.permanent = True
review_payment.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=30)

tried this but not geting

are you sure it executes these line? Or maybe it generate error and you don't see it - maybe you have except: pass which hides all problem. Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
